# Passing std::vector to function

Tags: c++

I want to add some values to a vector in my c++ code but every time I try and send the vector to the function in my main.cpp file it underlines it in red and say:

```
 A nonstatic member reference mus be relative to a specific object.
```

In my Header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <vector>

namespace Functions{
    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        void fun(std::vector<char*> vect);

    };

}
#endif
```

.cpp file:

```
void Functions::MyClass::fun(std::vector<char*> vect){
    vect.push_back("value 1");
    vect.push_back("Save File Name");
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"    
#include <vector>
int main(){ 
  std::vector<char*>vect;
  Functions::MyClass::fun(vect);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to pass that vector by reference.

Comment: create an object of class and pass vector to it as reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are calling a non-static function without an object. To fix that declare an object of type MyClass and call `fun` on it:

   ```
   int main(){ 
     Functions::MyClass a;
     std::vector<char*>vect;
     a.fun(vect);
     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. You only modify a local copy of `vect` in your function. To fix that pass the vector by reference to the function:

   ```
   void Functions::MyClass::fun(std::vector<char*>& vect){
     vect.push_back("value 1");
     vect.push_back("Save File Name");
   }
   ```

Of course declaration should also be changed accordingly.

Comment: OP: please consider accepting Andy Prowl's answer instead of mine as it is more detailed and also proposes another important improvement.

Answer (score 10):

You are calling your `fun()` member function as if it were a static function. Since it is a regular member function instead, you should create an object on which to invoke it:

```
Functions::MyClass m;
m.fun(vect);
```

If your function does not need to work on any concrete instance of the class it is a member of, you can declare it as `static`. That would allow you to call it the way you are currently calling it.

Besides, as others have pointed out already, it is probably a good idea to pass the vector *by reference*:

```
void fun(std::vector<char*>& vect)
//                         ^
```

Passing by value will create a *copy* of the argument in `vect`, meaning that the calling function will not see any side-effect after the call to `fun()`.

Also, a good idea is to use `std::string` rather than pointers to `char` (especially if not `const`):

```
#include <string> // Requires for std::string

// ...

void Functions::MyClass::fun(std::vector<std::string>& vect)
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    vect.push_back("value 1");
    vect.push_back("Save File Name");
}
```

Comment: If I were the one the choose I would accept this answer. Very good point on `std::string`, I did not notice the usage of `char*`.